# Proving a function to be a contraction

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I'm studying contractions and I am trying to understand under which conditions a function is actually a contraction. 
I have understood that a continuous function $f: [a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a contraction if:

i) $f$ is a selfmap, and

ii) given that it is differentiable on $(a,b)$, $|f'(x)|\leq\alpha$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$

Are these conditions right?
If so, why $f(x)=arctan(x)+5$ should not be a contraction in the complete metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a contraction, the (sufficient) condition you state would require $\alpha < 1$.
Your example with $\arctan$ will only provide $\alpha =1$ (as $f^\prime(0)=1)$. I.e., it is in particular $1$-Lipschitz (as a differentiable function with derivative bounded by $c$ is $c$-Lipschitz).

However, a contraction requires [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) $\alpha$-Lipschitz with $\alpha < 1$. (And one can verify that your $f$ is *not* $\alpha$-Lipschitz for any $\alpha < 1$, as around $0$ we have $\lvert f(x) - f(0)\rvert = \lvert x\rvert  + o(x)$.)

Comment: So the problem is that $|f'(x)|\leq1$ $\forall x\in[a,b]$ because I need an $\alpha\in(0,1)$ as from the definition of $\alpha$-contraction?

Comment: Yes -- you get $\alpha=1$ (showing the function is "non-expanding"), but you would need to establish $\alpha < 1$ (the function is "contracting").